# Find a Function Call Across All Contract Transactions

Tags: contract-development, transactions, contract-invocation, etherscan, contract-debugging

**Is it possible to search for a particular function call across all transactions of a smart contract?**

I'm doing due diligence on 1inch's *[smart contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x111111111117dc0aa78b770fa6a738034120c302)* in order to see if `renounceOwnership` was called and thus no further tokens can be minted using the external `mint` function.

So far I've been going through the *[first transactions](https://etherscan.io/txs?a=0x111111111117dc0aa78b770fa6a738034120c302&p=2000)* on Etherscan in the contract manually looking at the *Input Data* and *Logs*.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do this with code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## View Smart Contract Function Calls With *[Bloxy](https://bloxy.info)*

Search for the smart contract using its' address with Bloxy.

i.e. 1inch smart contract address: *[`0x111111111117dC0aa78b770fA6A738034120C302`](https://bloxy.info/address/0x111111111117dC0aa78b770fA6A738034120C302)*

Scroll down to the *Smart Contract Function Calls* section to view all smart contract function calls made.

[image]

FYI - It seems 1inch never called `renounceOwnership`, therefore an unlimited amount of 1NCH tokens can be created.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with code?